# Ext.Ajax.isLoading return false when not all requests were completed

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, extjs4.1

I need to do some action on panel after all Ajax requests completed and for this purpose I added handler:

```
Ext.Ajax.on('requestcomplete', function(conn, response, options) {
    if (!Ext.Ajax.isLoading()) {
        // do action
    }
});
```

But I found that in case when execute request by `Ext.Ajax.request` method Ext.Ajax.isLoading() return `false` regardless in which state this request.

**UPDATE**

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'someUrl',
    timeout: 50000,
    scope: this,
    success: function(response, options) {
        //some action
    },
    params: {
        //some params
    },
    callback: function() {
        //some action            
    }
});
```

Do someone know how to fix it? Or possible exist some other way for define that all requests completed?

Comment: What your `Ext.Ajax.request` and other code looks like?

Comment: @AntoJurkovic it's simple requests, nothing unusual. Added example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the `isLoading()` function only tells you if the request is still waiting for an answer. So false means that it hasn't started yet or it is finished.

If you know how many requests you're going to send in your panel, you could make a workaround using the native `setInterval()` function.

it could look like this:

```
var itemsLoaded = 0, 
    loadFailed = false,
    pID;

for(var i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
  Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'someUrl',
    timeout: 50000,
    scope: this,
    success: function(response, options) {
        itemsLoaded++;
        //other actions
    },
    failure: function() {
        loadFailed = true;
    },
    params: {
        //some params
    },
    callback: function() {
        //some action            
    }
  });
}

pID = setInterVal(function() {
  if(itemsLoaded == amount) {
    clearInterval(pID);
    //place here the actions you want to do when all items are loaded
  } else if(loadFailed) {
    clearInterval(pID);
  }
}, 100); //milliseconds you want to retry the check
```